# How to configure iptables correctly

Tags: iptables

I'm a newbie to linux.I just implemented the following commands in *iptables* which I found on a site for security (i don't understand much about how each rule works). The commands are as follows:

```
$IPTABLES -P INPUT DROP
$IPTABLES -P FORWARD DROP
$IPTABLES -P OUTPUT DROP

$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP

$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ACK,RST,SYN,FIN -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP

$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -f -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP  

$IPTABLES -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP

$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ACK,RST,SYN,FIN -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP

$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -f -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP
```

After implementing these i wasn't able to browse anything. How to correct my possible errors?

Answer (score 3):

You must understand that the third first lines disabled all traffic from,to and through your computer by default (`-P DROP`).

If you are to use IP tables with these default rules, the subsequent rules are meant to allow traffic. This is done using `ACCEPT` rules somewhere.

For example, you could allow incoming port 80 packets:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

On the other hand, you can proceed the other way, that is to say, allow all traffic by default `-P ACCEPT`, then write the particular things you need to disallow.

There is not much I can do for you but suggest that you read the iptables manual to understand how it works. You won't get security off the shelf with iptables.

Answer (score -1):

As you're starting out I would suggest ditching everything that you have right now and starting with some basics that you will give you the biggest wins.

For example:

```
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

# Drop a persistent nuisance
-A INPUT -s 89.163.185.170 -j DROP

# Accept established connections and loopback traffic

-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow ssh from our IP address 1.2.3.4 (but also use hosts.allow and hosts.deny files)
-A INPUT -s 1.2.3.4 -i eth0 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow web traffic on port 80 and 443 from everywhere
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Block everything else
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

You can build on this easily.

Comment: No, he can't build on this easily. Not understanding iptables at all means that he's just adding rules randomly; handing him a bunch - including one with a specific public IP address - doesn't help.

Comment: @Gabe - it's tempting to assume that others are like ourselves, but you should not judge the ability of *others* unless you know them personally; even though the OP is a self-proclaimed newbie, he may be a fast learner and have general experience that enables him to adequately research, extrapolate and understand sufficiently a reasonably well formatted and documented file. There may well be other questions that follow, but a modest example is a good starting point and stepping stone.

Answer (score -1):

You missed allowing `ESTABLISHED` connections. Try adding this at the end of your script

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Also I woud start restricting the incoming data first. You output rules only prevent special "hand-crafted" packages from being sent. When you worry about malicious software this does not help much, as these usually simply connect to remote servers using ordinary "correct" packets.

Comment: He missed allowing anything at all, anywhere.

Comment: And how did you become familiar with iptables? Didn't you start like him too? Give him hints and let him play. This should be obvious.